# struts menu - 'active' menu css doesnt work

Tags: struts

I am using struts menu in my project.

The problem is the active menu does not get high lighted.  I figured out where the logic for this is -

In ccHorizontalMenu.vm

```
#if ($menu.name == $currentMenu)
    <a href="$url" title="$title" class="current" #if($menu.target)target="$menu.target" #end#if($menu.width)style="width: ${menu.width}px"#end>${title}</a>
#else
    <a href="$url" title="$title" #if($menu.target)target="$menu.target" #end#if($menu.width)style="width: ${menu.width}px"#end>${title}</a>
#end
```

Since I have not set the $currentMenu variable the condition is failing and #else is getting executed.  On googling I found $currentMenu should be set like this -

```
<c:set var="currentMenu" scope="request"><decorator:getProperty property="meta.menu"/></c:set>
```

but I dont know where to set it....also where is meta.menu defined??

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the code to default.jsp and it worked!

I close my own issue.